# QuickBooks: Merge a Database with a Backup?

Tags: quickbooks

Assuming bad-case scenario of a QuickBooks backup that is X years out of date (this is not about the merits of backing up).

Is it possible to merge a current, up-to-date, QuickBooks 2013 database with the backup to restore lost data?

The situation is that we have a 2013 backup of a database we have been managing since 1996.  We recently re-typed an Account from Bank to Expense, which removed the Check Number from all of the Account Transactions.  After discovering the error, we re-typed the Account to a Bank account, however, we lost all Check Numbers for the history of the database.

The 2013 backup contains all Check numbers from 1996 to 2013, and we can easily manually reconcile the Transactions from 2013 to today.

Is it possible to take the 2013 backup, and fast-forward to, or merge it with, the current head of the current Database?

I have heard mumblings of editing an Export in Excel, which is fine for this kind of task, but I would not know where to begin to look to do this.

The theory is: If we can take the current Database, and resolve (perhaps by Transaction ID) check numbers from the 2013 backup, and then import this "updated" database, we would pretty much be all set.

I understand that it may not be "that" easy, but if there is a way to get access to *look* at this data, I am sure I would be able to figure something out.

And then, there is making regular backups...

Answer (score 0):

There's not a great way to import Excel data built into QuickBooks, so your best bet would be to use a third party utility to export/import the data. I would recommend the Data Transfer Utility application, as it's designed to do exactly what you are looking for (http://marketplace.intuit.com/appid-2309-overview.aspx)

You'll need to restore the old database into it's own separate file, which when you restore, just give the restored file a new name.